# Switching b/w the Tabs in Android(Chrome) in crossbrowsertesting platform using Appium/Selenium

Tags: android, selenium, mobile, cross-browser, appium

I am working on crossbrowsertesting platform in Android Chrome and facing a challenge in which I need to click on a link that opens up in new tab. I need to switch to that new tab and get its URL.
Problem is I am unable to switch to newly opened tab and get its URL.

Method used -
When using driver.switchTo().window(child_window) I am getting below error -

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: 'name'
>   must be a string.

But the same is working fine in Windows based chrome (not Android chrome browser).

Platform Information :

crossbrowsertesting
"browserName", "Chrome"
"deviceName", "Galaxy S9"
"platformVersion", "9.0"
"platformName", "Android"
"deviceOrientation", "portrait"

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the details of Appium/Selenium being used for testing?
I found this very similar bug here: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13106 
Please check you version is above 1.15, to confirm the fix is present in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in `chromedriver` itself. `W3C` protocol requires the call to POST /window to have handle parameter set, but chromedriver still wants `name` as in `JSONWP`. Specs is [here](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-switch-to-window)

It has been  tested on Appium  Beta version  **v1.14.0-beta.2** and it worked successfully on Android. Please update your appium library with this version atleast or higher to this version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

My project involved both web and native view so below is what I did

1- used chromeDriver with compatible Android emulator version

2- Switch to proper view

3- used driver.switchTo().window()

Thanks everyone for answers.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please consider using code notation for your code above. You might also elaborate on step 3.